# Force make to look at files before conclude to a circular dependency

Tags: makefile

I have a circular dependency using make:

```
CC              = gcc
IFLAGS          = -Iinclude
CFLAGS          = -Wall -g -c -fPIC -pedantic
AFLAGS          = -shared
LFLAGS          =
VERSION         = $(shell cat desc/major).$(shell cat desc/minor).$(shell cat desc/patch)
DFLAGS          = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -DLTKVER=\"$(VERSION)\"

OBJECTS         = $(patsubst src/%.c,tmp/%.o, $(shell ls -1 src/*.c))

#OUTPUT         = tmp/$(lastword $(subst /, ,$(shell pwd)))
OUT_BIN         = install/usr/lib/libLTK.so
OUT_MAN         = $(patsubst man/%,install/usr/share/man/%.gz, $(shell find man -type f))
PATH_INCLUDE    = install/usr/include/LTK-$(VERSION)
OUT_INCLUDE     = $(patsubst %,$(PATH_INCLUDE)/%, $(shell find include -type f -printf "%f\n"))
PC              = %

all: $(OUT_BIN) $(OUT_MAN) $(OUT_INCLUDE)
#   chmod 755 install/usr/lib/libLTK.so.$(VERSION)
    ln -sf install/usr/lib/libLTK.so.$(VERSION) install/usr/lib/libLTK.so
#   chmod 755 install/usr/include/LTK-$(VERSION)
#   chmod 644 install/usr/include/LTK-$(VERSION)/*
    ln -sf install/usr/include/LTK-$(VERSION) install/usr/include/LTK

$(OUT_BIN): $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)
    $(CC) $(AFLAGS) -o $@.$(VERSION) $^ $(LFLAGS)

tmp/%.o : src/%.c
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(DFLAGS) $(IFLAGS)

install/usr/share/%.gz : %
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)
    gzip -c $< > $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.h : $$(patsubst $(PATH_INCLUDE)/$$(PC),include/$$(PC),$$@)
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $$@)
    cp $< $$@

clean:
    rm -rf tmp install
```

At second expansion header files, prerequisites are generated from second expansions.
But it's a header that generates another and this new one can be found on the disk.
But make rather prefers to consider a circular dependency and ignore it.
How can I force make to see that the file exists before it searches a target to generate it?

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to ask "Is my build process too complicated? How can I make it more straightforward?" Think outside the box and maybe avoid an x-y-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular dependences are completely independent of what exists on the disk or doesn't exist on the disk.  When make runs it parses the makefile and constructs a graph representing the dependency relationship between targets.  This graph must be acyclic, because make will walk the graph looking for whether targets are out of date.  If there's a cycle in the graph, then make would recurse forever trying to walk the graph.

For example:

```
a: b ; touch $@
b: a ; touch $@
```

It doesn't matter whether these files exist or not: make still needs to be sure that "a" is newer than "b" to satisfy the first dependency, and that "b" is newer than "a" to satisfy the second dependency.

This cannot ever be true, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved by substituing $(OUT_INCLUDE) to %.h.

The goal to auto copy include files is preserved.
Substitued this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OUT_INCLUDE) : $$(patsubst $(PATH_INCLUDE)/$$(PERCENT),include/$$(PERCENT),$$@)
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)
    cp $< $@
```

For this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.h : $$(patsubst $(PATH_INCLUDE)/$$(PC),include/$$(PC),$$@)
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $$@)
    cp $< $$@
```

But I'm still asking myself on "is there anything to force file before dependency".
After looking at the code it looks like no, unless I omit something.